# BLE 4.3 startScan() cause losing of the connected device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

When I connect a BLE device then call `startScan()`, this causes the loss of the connected device. 
  Has anyone else had this problem? How do I resolve it?

thank you for help!
 
sorry ,there i had make a mistake. 
the source is :

```
mbtManager =(BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE); 
mbtAdapter = mbtManager.getAdapter();mbtAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback); 

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override 
    public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub Log.i(TAG, "="+device); 
    } 

};
```

when i had connected thd device just like the android ble 4.3 sample with BluetoothLeService .

when i startLeScan() ,it cause the lossing of the device which had connected.

Comment: Post your code. We can't help you unless you give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wait before start a new scan? In my app it works.

If I connect the phone to a BLE device and then start a new scan too early, the connection with the BLE device drops down. So I tried to wait some sec before attempt a new scan, and the connection doesn't drop down.
The BLE device I used is a Nordic nRF8002 tag